# Aggregate root Domain Logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, domain-driven-design

Suppose that I have these 3 classes below :

```
public class User 
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Location> { get; set; }
}
public class Location
{
   public int LocationId { get; set; }
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
}
public class Sale
{
  public int SaleId { get; set; }
  public int LocationId { get; set; }
  public decimal Cash { get; set; }
}
```

I have a requirement on a single page that I'll display the Total Cash for all locations of the user who's logged in. I'm thinking of I'll putting the GetTotalCash() method on the Locations class and implement the summation there by LINQ but the problem is I'll be accessing the Locations object through the User class and I won't be able to call the summation method since Location property is an ICollection on User class. Should I put the logic on the User class instead? but that doesn't makes sense since its not a behavior of the User object or does it?

By the way, I'm using EF 4.1 Code First and MVC 3.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Implement `GetTotalCash()` method in the locations class, and in the user class implement `GetCashForLocation()` to get the cash for a selected location (which will delegate the call to `GetTotalCash()` of the locations class, and implement `GetTotalCash()` in the user class which will iterate all locations and sum the cashes of them.

then the reprehensibilites are assigned per information expert class and delegated from the aggregate root

Comment: "then the reprehensibilites are assigned per information expert class and delegated from the aggregate root". What do you mean by this?

Comment: Also, it seems GetCashForLocation should belong to a repository?

Comment: Information Expert is one of GRASP patterns http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)
these patterns describe where should you design methods and how to assign responsibilities.

Comment: about GetCashForLocation .. if User is loaded fully with all its locations and sales then there is no need to fetch these info again from repository as it is already loaded in the user, if it is not loaded then repository is the right place

Comment: Thanks for the link. As for the loading with all of its locations, I'm using EF and it will automatically load related entities since lazy loading is enabled.